# How to pass a value from server side page to client side function in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I need to pass a string value from the server side(.aspx.cs) to a function in the client side (.aspx) page.

Can anyone help me by providing ideas and sample code if possible?

Answer (score 9):

If you mean that you need to pass the value to a javascript function, what you can do is something like this...

In the .aspx file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var stringValue = '<%=GetStringValue();%>';

  // For example:

  alert(stringValue);
</sctipt>
```

In the .aspx.cs file:

```
private string GetStringValue()
{
  return "A string value";
}
```

This would then show a javascript messagebox saying "A string value" when the page loads

Answer (score 2):

You can either generate the script on the server side and embed the value in it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"");
sb.Append("var someFunc = function(){");
sb.AppendFormat("alert('{0}');", importantServerSideValue);
sb.Append("};");
sb.Append("</script>");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock("genScript", sb.ToString());
```

Or place the value in a hidden form element on the page and access it from the client side Javascript.

```
<!-- In the Markup -->
<asp:HtmlInputHidden id="hiddenField" runat="server" />

// And in the code-behind
hiddenField.Value = importantServerSideValue;
```

Comment: StringBuilder to build scripts to inject into the page, aaargh, my eyes! ;-) The hidden input field is much better though :)

Comment: @Rob - Hehe. I usually default to building the script in the code behind unless the OP states he doesn't need to use any of the special methods of Registering the script (like Registering it as a startup script, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

When I had to pass a variable value from PHP to JS, I used php to echo out the js with a variable set to the php variable's value. e.g.

```
//php code
echo 'var number = ' . $variable . ';';
```