# How to pass a value from the serverside page to a function in .JS file in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have to pass a string value from the server side page (.aspx.cs) to a function in .JS page. I need to call the function in JS page from  server side page along with string as a parameter.

Can anyone please help me by providing samples or ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: @user311077 - how is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371642/how-to-pass-a-value-from-server-side-page-to-client-side-function-in-asp-net/ ? If it's not, please be a bit clearer about what you mean or this question will end up being closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a JS method with a server-side variable, you can do something like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("SomeKey", "functionToCall('" + stringValueOnServer + "');", true);
```

This renders functionToCall('value'); so that the proper call happens, but functionToCall must be defined before this.  Basically, have the script pretty high up in the page.

Comment: But the function used to call or pass the value to the .JS page is not in the page load....Can i use the "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript" for the functions which is not in the PAGE LOAD????? I tried but its not working.....

UR THOUGHTS

Comment: This can be called on the server-side at any point, PreRender works too, or Init.  I'm not sure what you mean by that; the Page property, has a ClientScript property, and the RegisterStartupScript method is used to register JavaScript code within the page at runtime....  could you clarify your question?